# Git won't accept PAT and thinks it's a password

Tags: git, personal-access-token

I want to clone my repository and got a prompt that I could no longer use passwords, and had to instead use a Personal Access Token.

But whenever I try to enter it (either in the popup window or the CMD directly) it keeps telling me I can't use passwords anymore and need a PAT. I'm putting it in the password field both times.

The PAT has the highest possible rights I could give it.

Comment: Git itself doesn't know a password from a coronary bypass. It just takes whatever you type in and feeds it to something else. It's the "something else" that's causing the problem here. Why switching to bash from cmd makes any difference is a mystery too, but it's still something other than Git itself causing the problem.

Comment: I believe this question is actually about GitHub, because GitHub changed from passwords to access tokens a year or two ago; and I have had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I randomly tried GIT BASH instead of the CMD and the second prompt did accept the PAT for the password field. I'd still like to know why this is the case.